# How many primitive elements does GF(256) have?

Tags: polynomials, coding-theory, primitive-roots

I know the answer for this is 36 but I don't exactly know how to reach to this. Can you any one help me in understanding this.

Comment: Why do you think the answer is $36$?

Comment: 256 = 255 -1 = 17.5.3 = 255.(1-1/17).(1-1/5).(1-1/3)  ??

Comment: $GF(64)$ has $36$ primitive elements, not $GF(256)$.

Comment: Primitive elements in $GF(256) = GF(2^8)$ come in sets of $8$ conjugates since primitive elements are roots of primitive binary polynomials of degree 8. So $36$ cannot possibly be correct.

Answer (score 1):

The number of primitive elements in a finite field $GF(n)$ is $φ(n - 1)$, where $φ(m)$ is Euler's totient function. Now compute $\phi(255)$. Use that $255=3\cdot 5\cdot 17$.

Comment: OK. But how does 36 come out of it?

Comment: That means there are only 3?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).

Comment: I am still confused about solving this problem.

Comment: 128? is this correct

Comment: $\phi(255)=\phi(3)\cdot \phi(5)\cdot \phi(17)=2\cdot 4\cdot 16$.

Answer (score 0):

[An article about Primitive Polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitivePolynomial.html) in Wolfram Mathworld says,

> There are
>   $$a_q(n)=\frac{\phi(q^n-1)}{n}$$
>   primitive polynomials over $\mathrm{GF}(q)$, where $\phi(n)$ is the totient function.

So, the number of primitive polynomials over $\mathrm{GF}(2^8)$ is supposed to be $\phi(255)/8=16$.